# Он добровольно сварил кашу и(,) несмотря ни на что(,) начал... Нужны запятые?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, предлоги, деепричастия

Он добровольно сварил кашу и(,)несмотря ни на что(,) начал... Нужны запятые?

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите полный вариант предложения. Обособление оборота факультативное и зависит от структуры предложения. К тому же сам оборот многозначный (у него разнообразный ряд синонимов), и поэтому надо понимать его значение в данном случае.

Answer (score 1):

*Он сварил кашу и, **несмотря ни на что**, начал...*

Решение об обособлении этого оборота можно принять, исходя из намеченной  структуры предложения. Да, оборот обособляется, так как в этой позиции **вряд ли возможна его тесная смысловая связь** с предложением.

В приведенном примере необособленный  вариант возможен при перестановке слов, например:

*Он **несмотря ни на что** сварил кашу и начал...*

*Он сварил кашу и **несмотря ни на что** начал...*

Пояснение

1. О **тесной смысловой связи** говорит Розенталь в своих правилах: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=114#pp114

Оборот с предложным сочетанием НЕСМОТРЯ НА как правило, обособляется: Несмотря на запрет врачей, он поехал в далёкую таёжную экспедицию. Однако при тесной смысловой связи с господствующим словом, после которого он находится, оборот этот не обособляется: Явился дежурный администратор, вызванный несмотря на поздний час.

2. А это информация из **Справочника по пунктуации:** http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_860

НЕСМОТРЯ НИ НА ЧТО, в роли обстоятельственного оборота

Обстоятельственный оборот «несмотря ни на что» чаще выделяется знаками препинания (запятыми): *Весеннее ли расположение подействовало на него, или толкал его кто сзади, только он протеснялся решительно вперед, **несмотря ни на что**. Матушка, которая до самой смерти своей страстно любила его, **несмотря ни на что**, не могла выносить такой жизни.*

3. Тем не менее необособленный оборот встречается в текстах, например:
   Как-то Пальчикову пришла мысль, что, если Бога **несмотря ни на что нет**, то ему, Пальчикову, это будет, вероятно, не так страшно и не так обидно… [А. Н. Бузулукский, 2014]

Ребёнок скорее прислушается к вашим советам и последует им, когда видит, что его по-настоящему любят **несмотря ни на что.**

А значит, независимый доступ в космос России **несмотря ни на что** будет обеспечен. [Алексей Хазбиев, 2014]

Однако врачи **несмотря ни на что** продолжали реанимационные мероприятия.

Учит детей **несмотря ни на что,** даёт им уроки дома, сам ходит по ученикам.

В некоторых из этих примеров возможны **оба варианта,** тогда это авторское решение (смысловое выделение оборота при обособлении).